# can't encode a WAV file to FLAC; returns 'ERROR: unsupported format type 3'

Tags: linux, audio, conversion, flac, wav

The error reportedly originates from files created on Windows. When attempting to convert, `flac 1.4.3` prints:

```
$ flac --best ~/music/unknown-80s-german-song.wav
unknown-80s-german-song.wav: ERROR: unsupported format type 3
```

I opened the file in Audacity 3.4.2 (Flatpak) and attempted exporting — the program defaults to 'signed 16-bit PCM' encoding while the file presents itself as 32-bit:

```
$ mediainfo ~/music/unknown-80s-german-song.wav
General
Complete name                            : /home/user/music/unknown-80s-german-song.wav
Format                                   : Wave
Format settings                          : PcmWaveformat
File size                                : 60.6 MiB
Duration                                 : 2 min 59 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 2 822 kb/s

Audio
Format                                   : PCM
Format profile                           : Float
Codec ID                                 : 3
Codec ID/Hint                            : IEEE 
Duration                                 : 2 min 59 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 2 822 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Bit depth                                : 32 bits
Stream size                              : 60.6 MiB (100%)
```

For automation I prefer a command-line method.

---

While this is on the grey area (the state of copyright = **unknown**), [the file emerged on a community centered around a certain unidentified song](https://old.reddit.com/r/TheMysteriousSong/comments/qyhw82/highquality_version_of_the_newly_found_copy_of_tms/) (digitized tape).

Comment: I updated my answer since you accepted it with an advice using sndfile-convert. Please try it, I'd be interested to know the result of the direct conversion into flac.

Comment: I'll keep the WAV file around for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ERROR: unsupported format type 3

Type 3 is associated to the [WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT wave format](https://chromium.googlesource.com/vcbox/third_party/libsox/+/refs/heads/master/src/src/wav.c).

```
#define WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT          (0x0003U)
```

So you are asking flac to encode a **floating point** encoded .wav when, [as far as stated](https://xiph.org/flac/2022/09/09/flac-1-4-0-released.html), flac does not (yet?) support that :

> FLAC can now encode and decode 32 bit-per-sample audio… **Note that
> this is 32 bit integer samples, not 32 bit float samples**.

You should be able to convert the samples to 32 bits integers from the command-line using [sndfile-convert](https://www.mankier.com/1/sndfile-convert) from the quasi-standard libsndfile. Something like

```
sndfile-convert -pcm32 ~/music/unknown-80s-german-song.wav converted_result
```

Note that 32 bits float using a 24 bits mantissa, it should in fact result in a 24 bits per sample file.

Also note that `sndfile-convert` appears from the doc capable to output in flac format in the same go by specifying the .flac extension to the name of the output file. (I did not test that though)

---

OP's experience returns that `sndfile-convert` does not appear capable to achieve both conversions in the same go, something [sox](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sox) should be capable of according to [Austin Hemelgarn](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/240409/austin-hemmelgarn)

```
sox ~/music/unknown-80s-german-song.wav -t flac -e signed-integer -b 24 -C 8 ~/music/unknown-80s-german-song.flac
```

should convert floating-point samples to 24 bits signed integers and convert to flac with a compression factor of 8 in the same go.

Comment: The `pcm32` part of the command is missing a hyphen (I lack the edit rights).

Comment: Sadly can't directly transcode to FLAC: `$ sndfile-convert -pcm32 ~/music/unknown-80s-german-song.wav /tmp/german.flac`: `Error : output file format is invalid. \ The 'FLAC' container does not support '32 bit PCM' codec data.` — but great nonetheless, when outputting to WAV `flac` is able to encode the said file... but prints `german.wav: WARNING: legacy WAVE file has format type 1 but bits-per-sample=32`.

Comment: The package I used is `libsndfile-utils-1.1.0-9.fc39.x86_64`.

Comment: Alternatively to `sndfile-convert`, possibly install [SoX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/) (found in most distros’ standard repos with the package name `sox`), and use `sox ~/music/unknown-80s-german-song.wav -t flac -e signed-integer -b 24 -C 8 ~/music/unknown-80s-german-song.flac`, which will convert directly to FLAC with appropriate sample-type conversion and maximal FLAC compression. I’ve personally found SoX to be more flexible and more intuitive to work with for stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks @AustinHemmelgarn for suggesting. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn SoX v14.4.2 returns the warnings "sox WARN wav: wave header missing extended part of fmt chunk" and 
"sox WARN formats: flac can't encode Signed Integer PCM". The file is successfully converted (the output FLAC is around 1/3 of the size).